# Leaflet Zoom Control +/- Appearance

Tags: leaflet, zooming

I've noticed that the Leaflet Zoom Control has an underline with the + and -. Is there anyway to remove the underlines? I've tried changing the 'text' but that text is also underlined.

TIA for any assistance
jdadwilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normaly the underline is not visbile, but I think you have defined your own CSS and there you have overwritten the `text-decoration` property with `text-decoration: underline !important` for all `a` elements.

Don't use `!important` if it is not necessary.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.leaflet-bar a, .leaflet-bar a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the leaflet CSS classes got changed

Try the following incase the above didn't work

```
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```